# how to add button subview after removefromsubview uibutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

[image]

I want to hide and show button from multiple button. Auto layout other button automatically

```
 fiveBtn.tag = 1000;
 [[self.view viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
 fiveBtn=nil;
```

after i want to add again in storyboard
below image please check ...
while clicking four the button five button hide and while clicking third button five button show .. my problem auto layout

Comment: your question is not clear,

Comment: Clear you question, What you want exactly and what you did so far?

Comment: unable to get.. what do you want to achieve.

Comment: Take Outlet  of  `fiveBtn` instead of tag, and after ` removeFromSuperview` add it again using `addSubview`

Comment: Why you are removing from superview rather than hide it ?

Comment: In stroyBoard if you are using autoLayouts, then it is not correct to remove and add the button. Programatically disable the userInteraction of button and set button text to empty string, clear background colour.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to group your views under a stack view. Then when you hide a particular view, the remaining views will be shifted automatically to fill the space.

You may want to check out the Apple Documentation on Stack Views: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview

or online tutorials such as: https://www.appcoda.com/stack-views-intro/